# fix vertical scroll bar in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, scrollbar

I've a website, and in my main page page scroll bar is gone. There are six collapsible panels, all of them fixed by always visible control extender. After I add them main page, it broke.
I'm working with asp.net 4.0.

[image]

Comment: What does "broken" mean?

Comment: page scroll is not visible so rest of page...

Comment: I don't understand the question. When they are extended are they "overflowing" the end of the page? Can you post a screen shot? :-)

Comment: Have you asked the same question twice? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156823/fix-collapsible-menu-position

Comment: @IrishChieftain they are not the same questions, link you gave about my collapsible panels positions to fix this but question is about page scroll bar rigth side of page when page is overflowing the screen... i found an javascript code but it doesnt work... besides i couldnt add the screen shot if you can tell how i can i will do...

Comment: There's an image icon in the editor. Use that :-)

Comment: @IrishChieftain i  added the image im not sure but bad css can cause it?

Comment: @serim, see update in my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the CSS set the height in the body rule to 101%. There are other ways to do this but they are browser-specific and your page won't validate.

**UPDATE:**

Just as a check, try applying a [overflow:scroll;](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_pos_overflow.asp) rule to the div containing the right-hand section. The part on the right looks like it needs to be more to the left. Put everything in a container div and set a width of 960px on that. I think the scroll bar problem may be a side effect of some bad CSS. You need to debug this properly - try using the Firefox [Web Dev toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/web-developer/) - then start commenting out sections div by div to see what's really happening.

Comment: thx but it doesnt work, seems to give up using ajaxcontrol toolkit objects as a composite object

Comment: i couldnt try lastone beacuse my project file is corrupted but thx for help im sure its useful